# creating new instance in java classes

Tags: java

I'm new in java and I saw this sample code.  I don't know why in JavaApplication.java file we need to create a new instance by new keyword to set the goat name but in Tiger.java there is no need to create a new instance by new keyword to set the goat name! what's the difference?

JavaApplication.java

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Tiger t = new Tiger();
    Goat g = new Goat();
    Goat g1 = new Goat();
    g.name = "goaty";
    g1.name = "goatia";
    t.name = "woofy";
    t.hunt(g);
    t.hunt(g1);
}
```

Tiger.java

```
public class Tiger {
    String name;
    void hunt(Goat food) {
        System.out.println(name + " ate " + food.name);
    }
}
```

Goat.java

```
public class Goat {
    String name;
}
```

Comment: The client is directly accessing the field `name`.

Comment: *name* is class level default variable in Tiger,java whereas, in JavaApplication.java, you'll have to instantiate the class to use name property of Tiger class. It's the fundamental **OOPS** principle.

Comment: It is not really clear where you are struggling. If there is already an instance why create another one?

Comment: I mean the goat name @Abhinav

Comment: The goat object named "food" carries the goat name with it.

Comment: @Modus Tollens ok that's right... I mean why there is no need to "new" keyword to create food object?

Comment: In `void hunt(Goat food) {...}` method in Tiger.java, you aren't creating a new Goat object. Instead, you're expecting a Goat object (created somewhere) to be passed on to `hunt` method.

Comment: @jackpeterson Raihanul explains that in the comment above this one. You already created the object using "new" and just pass it over to the hunt method.

Answer (score 2):

In `Tiger` class inside the function `hunt`, `food` is a parameter of type `Goat` and a parameter doesn't need to be instantiated by the `new` keyword. Only the object needs to be instantiated.

Comment: "and a parameter doesn't need to be instantiated by the new keyword" -- To be more correct, the parameter variable does at some point need to be instantiated, its just that this instantiation is performed prior to calling the method.

Comment: What if the `food` is `null`? It will throw `NPE`. You should make a *fail-safe* method and instantiate `food` if it is null or check `food` before proceeding ;)

Answer (score 1):

I'm also new at java but what I understand in java is that you can't link non-static method/variable to a static one and in order to do so, you need to create an instance for it. :) the new keyword is needed to create an instance of it btw..

Comment: Good understanding you have.

Answer (score 1):

As far as i can see you have placed Goat food as parameter which means hunt method will accept an object of type Goat basically food is reference variable of type Goat.So any thing that a Goat can do should apply to food also.In your Goat class you have only a field of name .So whenever you create an object you can just give it a name that's it .Now you are passing Goat object into your method so in order to printout food.name your goat needs to have a name first.

Answer (score 1):

A Goat can be created only by using the `'new'` keyword. After a goat is created you can give this goat to a tiger to eat. 
So this goat here

```
 void hunt(Goat food) {
    System.out.println(name + " ate " + food.name);
}
```

is already created so you don't have to create it again. Of course you can initate it again but it would be pointless since if a tiger could create a goat by itself it would not need to hunt goats.